# Raspberry Pi Python IDLE vs. __init__.py

Tags: python, init

I am using the tsl2561 python package on my RPi in order to interact with the tsl2561 light sensor. However, I am having a really weird occurrence that I cannot understand. Let me try to explain it the best I can.

If I open up IDLE and run

```
from tsl2561 import *
```

then when I try to run the TSL2561(debug=True) command it does not work and says TSL2561 is not defined.

However, when I open up the **__init__**.py file located in the tsl2561 folder (which contains only one line "from tsl2561 import *"), and run that file, it opens a new IDLE window upon where I can type

```
TSL2561(debug=True)
```

and it recognizes the function and allows me to see the light level. But, if I open IDLE again in a new window and run

```
from tsl2561 import *
TSL2561(debug=True)
```

I get the error saying TSL2561 is undefined.

So, my question is, if you understand it, why does the function work when I run the **__init__** script which has the same line but not when I just open up IDLE and try to type the code myself?

Any help would be greatly appreciated because I need to be able to write a separate script without having to rely on always opening from the init file!

It is Python 3.4

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: I'd guess you have another file named `tsl2561.py` somewhere near where you're running your code the first time (where it doesn't work). That file is masking the library package, so you get errors about functions not existing. Try doing `import tsl2561` and then `print(tsl2561.__file__)`. I'd also generally recommend not doing `from module import *` since it can make debugging more difficult as its not clear whicht names were originally in which namespace.

Comment: @Blckknght Thanks for the response! I will check it out when I get home. I think you may be right. The folder /tsl2561 that containts the init file also has the file tsl2561.py. Should I change the name of the tsl2561.py file?